# Is T(n)=n/x sublinear in $n$?

Tags: time-complexity

I know sublinear time algorithm is expressed by o(n).

Is T(n)=n/x sublinear in $n$ for positive number x?

In other words, is n/x=o(n)?

Comment: It'll depend upon the value of x, if x is large close to n then it might be o(1).

Comment: @Atul Kumar We are talking about asymptotic behavior here. x is a constant  so it can not be "close to n" as n tends to infinity.

Comment: in asymptotic behaviour you need to check for your constant, as constant should not be very large. @jspurim

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your last comment. Anyway, my point is, this does not depend on the value of x. @AtulKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

`T(n) = n/x` is linear, in the same way as `T(n) = xn` is linear. If your function is just `n` multiplied by some constant `c`, then it's linear. In this particular case, `c=1/x`.

You can also check this using the [formal definition of small o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation).

> Formally, f(n) = o(g(n)) as n → ∞ means that for
>   every positive constant ε there exists a constant N such that |f(n)| <= ε|g(n)| for all n>= N.

In this case, pick `ε=1/2x` and you wont be able to find an `N` to satisfy the condition to make `n/x = o(n)`.

Intuitively, one says `f(n) = o(g(n))` if and only if `f(n)` is dominated by `g(n)` eventually even if you "slow g(n) down" multiplying it by a very small constant.

Comment: Can the constant c be rational number?

Comment: Yes, c can be any real number. If your function is supposed to represent execution time, then negative values of c would make no sense, but any positive real number is valid.

Concrete example: Consider the problem of, given an array `A` of sorted values, and a value `x`, determine whether `x` is above the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) of A. You can solve this by traversing half the array `A`, so if `A` has `n` elements you can solve this in `T(n) = n/2`. This algorithm is still linear, if you double the size of `A` it will take you twice as long to solve the problem.

Comment: You can solve the same problem using binary search in time `T(n) = log(n)`, and this would be a real sub linear solution (double the size of `A` and it won't take you twice as long).